# I cannot get the correct answer in a HTTP POST Request in Android, but in JQUERY that's ok

Tags: android, jquery, post, http-post

I'm starting to develop in android. I have a web page that receives a POST request (a login) and sends a response (0 when it's not ok or 1 when it's ok). I'm trying to call it from an Android App, but the response is always 0, as if the user of the logging was incorrect. The question is when I try to do this whit a request from JQUERY it's ok and the result is 1.

This is my JQUERY code:

```
<html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('document').ready(function () {
                $('#send').click(function () {                
                    var token = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678";
                    var email = "email@email.com";
                    var passw = "pass";
                    $.post("http://myURL", {
                        email: email,
                        passw: passw,
                        token: token

                    }, function (data, textStatus) {
                        if (data == 1) {//IT'S OK; THE RESULT IS 1
                            alert("correct!!");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("something is wrong!!");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<span id="send">Send</span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Android code:

```
    public class loginRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result = "";
                String sJSon = "";
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myURL"); 

                // build jsonObject
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {

                    jsonObject.accumulate("token", "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678");
                    jsonObject.accumulate("passw", "pass");
                    jsonObject.accumulate("email", "email@email.com");
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

                // convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                sJSon = jsonObject.toString();          

                //Encoding POST data
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(sJSon));
                    //Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //making POST request.
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    // write response to log

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if(entity != null){
                        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);//THE RESULT IS ALWAYS 0
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if ("1".equals(result))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery  is not sending json and you are. Just send name value pairs instead.